# The Range Slider doesn't change the volume property of an audio element in React

Tags: reactjs, state, html5-audio, volume

I have trouble changing the volume of audio elements.
Everything works fine, the slider is working fine, its value is changed, the state gets changed, but the audio is awlays playing at 0.5.
I am new to React and this is a project about a small "drum machine".

Any recommendations are welcome!

This is my Parent Component:

```
function App() {

  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0.5);
  const keyCodeArray = [81, 87, 69, 65, 83, 68, 90, 67];

  useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{handleKeyPress(e)});
  }, []);

  function handleKeyPress(e){
    if(keyCodeArray.indexOf(e.keyCode)){
      playSound(e);
  }
  }

  function playSound(e){
    let id = e.key.toUpperCase();
    let sound = document.getElementById(id);
    sound.volume = volume;
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.play();
  }

  return (
    <> 
      <Display />
      <Pads />
      <RangeSlider parentState={volume} parentStateSetter={(e)=> setVolume(Number(e))}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my Child Component:

```
function RangeSlider(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="range" 
            min='0' 
            max="1" 
            step='0.01' 
            value={props.parentState} 
            className='slider' 
            id="myRange" 
            onChange={(e)=> {
              props.parentStateSetter(Number(e.target.value))
            }}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vloume` in `playSound` is actually a copy of the real `volue` that set as a state, and will only be updated when the component rerender.

Also, the `handleKeyPress` added for event listener is also a copy of the function that defined inside `App`...

This may sound a bit complex, so, I'll try to explain with code below.

**To create a function in which the `volumn` will change when the state changes**

Wrap the function `playSound` with `useCallback` like this:

```
const playSound = useCallback((e) => {
    let id = e.key.toUpperCase();
    let sound = document.getElementById(id);
    sound.volume = volume;
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.play();
}, [volume]);
```

Now, the `volumn` inside of this `playSound` function will be updated while the state changes. (Actually, it's the **function** itself get updated, not just `volumn`)

Then, wrap the function `handleKeyPress` inside `useCallback` as well, since what we do above makes `playSound` to change with state update.

```
const handleKeyPress = useCallback((e) => {
    if (keyCodeArray.indexOf(e.keyCode)) {
        playSound(e);
    }
}, [playSound]);
```

The second parameter `[playSound]` means, the function `handleKeyPress` will update when `playSound` changes.

Now, all the functions will be updated when `volumn` is updated, which... is still not enough though, because when doing `addEventListener`, the function we pass is still a copy, not the real one that changing with `volumn`.
So we'll need to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const func = (e) => { handleKeyPress(e) };  // removeEventListener will need to pass the exact same function fot it to work, so do this here
    document.addEventListener('keydown', func);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', func);
    }
}, [handleKeyPress]);
```

The function useEffect returns will do a cleanup when new `handleKeyPress` appears.

Might fell a little confused in the beginning. That is how react state works.

Oh btw, the order of functions in the final code will need some change as well. Make sure to define before using.

```
const playSound = useCallback((e) => {
    // ...
}, [volume]);

const handleKeyPress = useCallback((e) => {
    // ...
}, [playSound]);

useEffect(() => {
    // ...
}, [handleKeyPress]);
```